# Code wrapped in single quotes in FOR statement's `IN` argument as command not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

On my windows PC, system is not taking code wrapped in single quotes in FOR statement's `IN` argument as command.

Please consider below code.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %F IN ('dir *') DO (echo %F)
```

Output

```
'dir *' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Here as you can see system is not taking `dir \b` as command but is trying to execute `'dir \b *'` i.e. including quote. Which whole is not a command.

I am using windows 7. The same code is working on other windows PC's. I am not able to figure out what difference is making this to not run on my machine.

Comment: doesn't solve your problem but it should be dir /b * (forward slash instead of backslash)

Comment: I've copied your statement and it runs on my machine (Windows server 2016)

Comment: @AcidJunkie The problem is not that bare parameter. The single quote is not working. (Now I removed that /b paramter)

Comment: even runs on my other win 7 machine. :/

Comment: There is something different installed, configured or setup on my computer that I cannot figure out which is making this command not work properly

Comment: Are you doing this on the command line? (If it's in a batch file you need `%%F`.)

Comment: Use two `%`-signs in a batch file for `for` variables!

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou This code is not working on command prompt. And the same is not working on batch file after using %%F in the place of %F. In short single quote is not working as expected.

Comment: What output do you get if you open a new Command Prompt window and enter, `DIR *`?

Comment: Your cause analysis is flawed. It is not trying to execute `'dir'` including the quotes. It uses the quotes to surround the command that it tells you is invalid. So in this case it's telling you that `dir` is an invalid command. You can test this by writing `for /f "delims=" %f in ('xxxx') do @echo %f` on the machines where the original command works ok.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou `dir` is giving me expected output when used directly in command prompt. And when I replaced `dir *` with `echo abc`, it is still not working on my machine but same is working on other computers.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You were right. The system is not able to find dir command when I write it inside single quotes. But it is working fine when used directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your value of the ComSpec variable. The command interpreter uses that to execute internal commands. If it's not cmd.exe, you'll get that error message:

```
C:\Users\klitos>set comspec=xxx

C:\Users\klitos>for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir') do @echo %f-
'dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To fix it:

```
C:\Users\klitos>set comspec=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

C:\Users\klitos>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\klitos>for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir') do @echo %f-
 Volume in drive C is OS-
```

Once you've identified the rogue bit of code that sets comspec to an incorrect value, fix that for a permanent solution.

Comment: @afzalex cmd.exe caches the comspec when it first starts. You will need to set comspec=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and then immediately start a new instance of cmd.exe from that command line. Then try the for /f command in that subprocess. (See edit.)